# Make browserify work with Google Closure Compiler

Tags: google-closure-compiler, browserify

I am trying to compile my code generated by browserify with Google Closure Compiler using Advanced Optimization.
Tried running browserify with different flags, no success so far.

Have any one have some experience with that?

Comment: Are you getting errors from the compiler? Or it's generating code that doesn't run? Need more details.

Comment: Compiler runs without errors.
When I run I get:

    `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'underscore'`

My guess the way browserify requires and exports modules does not play well with Closure?

Comment: @MichalKowalkowski Are you sure you required underscore in the appropriate file? Also, make sure you aren't passing in the window object (if you are).

Comment: Save & Open the browserified bundle. Then open and check if underscore js source is rendered in there somewhere. If not, then you haven't `require`d it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the file: /node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-pack/_prelude.js with google closure annotations and add the externs files as

```
/**
* @param {*=}o
* @param {*=}u 
*/
function require(o,u){}
```

What errors/warnings do you get?